# Disable selected cell border in Excel with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I disable the green border around a cell in Excel with VBA when the cell is selected (like my picture)?

Gridlines are hidden in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us why you're trying to do this? If I understand you properly, then you've written some VBA code that selects cells and you don't want the cell border that indicates the selection. If so, then the best option is not to select cells at all. In VBA, you don't have to select a cell to manipulate it.

Comment: Quote 'The colors used by Excel when you select items are controlled not by Excel, but by Windows. You can change the selection color, but you should understand that when you do so it may affect other programs besides just Excel.' - You can change the colour by changing 'Windows Color and Appearance' - The quote is taken directly from the following website (Credit to Allen Wyatt): https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008265_Changing_the_Color_Used_to_Denote_Selected_Cells.html